# Unable to access to the path contained in my modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using React.js and I created a button which open a modal and in this modal (Register/Login) there is a link where I can switch modal but when I click on this link nothing happen...

I don't know exactly why...

Here is my code App.js :

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import Login from "./Login";
import Register from "./Register";

export default function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleOpen = () => {
    setShow(true);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        <Button onClick={() => handleOpen()}>Test</Button>
      </div>
      <Register show={show} onClose={handleClose} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Here is the code of the first modal :

```
import React from "react";
import { Modal, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import './RegisterLoginModal.css'
import {BrowserRouter, Link, Redirect} from "react-router-dom";

const Register = (props) => {
  console.log(props);

    return (
      <Modal show={props.show} onHide={props.onClose} centered>
        <div className="login-form">
          <form className="form-signin" >
            

            
              <BrowserRouter><Link to="/login">
                <i className="fas fa-user-plus" /> Log in
              </Link></BrowserRouter>
          </form>
        </div>
      </Modal>
    );
  }

export default Register;
```

And there the code of the second modal :

```
import { Modal, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import React from "react";
import {BrowserRouter, Link, Redirect, Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
import Register from "./Register";

const Login = (props) => {
    console.log(props);

    return (
        <>
        <Modal show={props.show} onHide={props.onClose} centered>
            <div className="login-form">
                <form className="form-signin">

                    <BrowserRouter><Link to="/register">
                <i className="fas fa-user-plus" /> Sign up
              </Link></BrowserRouter>
                </form>
            </div>

        </Modal>
            <BrowserRouter>
                        <Switch>
    <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
  </Switch>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </>
    );
};

export default Login;
```

For instance when I click on the button Test I got that :

[image: Register]

And when I click on Log In I have no this

[image: Login]

whereas that's what I want and Reciprocally when I click on Sign Up and don't see Register.

Here is my full code :

[Switch modal](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-paper-e9d7l?file=/src/RegisterLoginModal.css)

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Login and Register Files are empty

Comment: Indeed I updated that

Answer (score 0):

Change your Login.js to this:

```
import { Modal, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Link, Redirect, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Register from "./Register";

const Login = (props) => {
  console.log(props);
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const handleOpen = () => {
    setShow(true);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Modal show={props.show} onHide={props.onClose} centered>
          <div className="login-form">
            <form className="form-signin">
              <Link to="/register" onClick={() => handleOpen()}>
                <i className="fas fa-user-plus" /> Sign up
              </Link>
            </form>
          </div>
        </Modal>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Worked in the sandbox with this.
**Route does not accept function components with parameters as I recall.**
So you cannot pass variables down to your Register.js.